# Validate date using v-validate in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to allow only those date that are equal to or greater than the departure date time field:

```html
<tr v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
  <datetime 
    name="departureDateTime"
    v-validate="'date_format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss|required'"
    v-model="input.departureDateTime"
  >
  </datetime>

  <datetime 
    name="arrivalDateTime"        
    v-validate="`after:${input.departureDateTime}|date_format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss|required`"
    v-model="input.arrivalDateTime"
  >
  </datetime>
<tr>
```

This is only allowing me dates which are after departureDateTime field in arrival field, but i also want it should allow the same date also i.e. if i fill 27-05-2021 in departure time then it should allow the same date in arrivalDateTime field also and i want to allow only future dates to be filled in both the date fields.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`after` params](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/rules.html#after-params) are:

```
after:target,inclusion
```

...where the `inclusion` flag (any value) specifies whether to check for dates greater than or equal to `target`.

So just add `,true` after the target date:

```html
<datetime 
  name="arrivalDateTime"                         
  v-validate="`after:${input.departureDateTime},true|date_format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss|required`"
  v-model="input.arrivalDateTime"
>
</datetime>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-date-time-range-in-veevalidate-forked-8y93k)